# libpl.so in Prolog version 6.6.4?

Tags: python, swi-prolog, shared-libraries

I was trying to connecting to Prolog from python, using pyswip package. I installed swipl using homebrew, and Following the [installation instruction of pyswip](https://code.google.com/p/pyswip/wiki/INSTALL), I added the `--enable-shared` when I was trying to do the './configure' when installing the swipl.

But I cannot find the `libpl.so` file in my swipl folder.

Any clues?

Comment: Were these the instructions you were following? http://code.google.com/p/pyswip/wiki/INSTALL What step did it fail on and what was the error message?

Comment: @mbratch Thx.. that's exactly the instruction I was following (sorry forgot to put the link.. I'll put later). Firstly, the link provided to download swipl is broken, so I used the one provided by homebrew; there was no error message, just that the libpl.so file is not generated.

Comment: @mbratch I tried going to the installed folder of swipl, in my case it's `/usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/6.6.4`, I did a `ls -R | grep "libpl"`, all I can find is just a "libpl.html" file.

Comment: OK, so it's possible the information on that link is not up to date. :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent SWI-Prolog versions renamed several executables and libraries, replacing "pl" in the name by "swipl". See if `libswipl.so` is available.

Comment: Thanks for your comments~ I only have "libswipl.a", and "libswipl.dylib". I don't know how much it's related to the .so file.. can I use any of the above as replacement?

Comment: `.dylib` is the Mac OS X equivalent to Linux `.so` dynamic shared libraries.

Comment: Your means is I rename file "libswipl.a" and "libswipl.dylib" to "libpl.a" and "libpl.dylib"? I did this but still I have an error